# Combining Akka, Spray, and embedded Jetty

Tags: scala, jetty, akka

I'm trying to create a standalone JAR containing Akka, Spray, and Jetty. Ideally I distribute the entire application in that single file, without any external files whatsoever.

I understand how to create an embedded Jetty server instance

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val server = new Server(9012);
    server.start();
    server.join();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    server.stop();
}
```

and I've followed the Spray example code in creating a HelloService and Boot class, but I have no earthly idea of how to connect the two, so that when a URL is requested on the Jetty server a Spray service responds to it. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update:** I'm getting a lot closer to solving this problem, thanks to a thread of inquiry prompted by Alois Cochard (I'm coming from a web scripting background, and getting my head around Java web services has been ... challenging!). I've modified my [main method](https://gist.github.com/1152888) to start the server and read the [Jetty](https://gist.github.com/1152893) and [akka configuration](https://gist.github.com/1152890) files that are in the getting started template. It's reading both of those files, but now I'm getting this when I navigate to / on the Jetty server:

> HTTP ERROR: 500
>
> Problem accessing /. Reason:
>
> assertion failed: 0 actors for id 'spray-root-service' found, expected exactly one

I know I'm missing something silly (and probably that I should break down and use SBT, but being able to just compile and run in Eclipse, and then refresh in the browser, is so simple and appealing).

**Update #2**: Figured out the problem. I wasn't creating a WebAppContext object, which meant that the web.xml was never getting read, and thus Akka was never being loaded. [This is the revised](https://gist.github.com/1152888) main method which is now working.

Comment: Do you know about [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the spray-template, you should add the Spray servlet connector in the web.xml configuration file:

http://github.com/spray/spray-template/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

You can find some informations about how to configure a standealone jetty to use this file here (there is surely better references in netty documentation directly):

http://exist.sourceforge.net/deployment.html#d47e594

BTW, using the spray template as a basis for your project looks like a good idea ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Alois. Didn't solve my problem directly, but it got me headed in the right direction and I eventually figured it out. Cheers!

Comment: @JohnBiesnecker, can you share your solution?

Comment: @tiagoboldt It's in the gist I linked to in the updates to the main question: https://gist.github.com/1152888